# Optimized AWS Lamda purpose

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, parquet

I'm looking for optimized code with faster execution time. This writes CSV to parquet with the max size of 64 MB chunks.

we are trying to concatenate the csv file contents being written as an parquet file until the parquet file size reaches 64MB

The loop would continue to run until reads all the csv files content being concatenated being written as parquet format

````
import pandas as pd
import uuid
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
out_path='s3://ahshan/parquet-out/'
ssize=64*1024*1024


def get_s3_keys(bucket, prefix):

    """Get a list of keys in an S3 bucket."""
    resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    files=[]
    for obj in resp['Contents']:
      str_key = obj['Key']
      files.append(str_key.split('\n'))
#      print(files)
    return files


def lambda_handler(event,context):
    counter=0
    count=0
    cond=False
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = get_s3_keys('ahshan','csvfiles/csvtemp/')
#    print (all_filenames)  
    df = []
    sizedf =0
    cond=False
    flat_list = [item for sublist in all_filenames for item in sublist]
    flatl= [ item for item in flat_list if '.csv' in item]
    print(' shiva pre :', flatl)
    for f in flatl:
        ipd = pd.read_csv('s3://ahshan/'+f)
        sizedf += ipd.size
        print(sizedf, ":", ssize)
        if sizedf > ssize:
            pd.concat(df).to_parquet(out_path+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.parq', compression='gzip')
            sizedf = 0
            df = []
            cond=True
        else:
            df.append(ipd)
            cond=False

    if not cond:
        print('hello')
        pd.concat(df).to_parquet(out_path+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.parq', compression='gzip')
```
````

Comment: With this condition `if sizedf > ssize:` all csv files whose records **size** is greater than `64`Mb will be skipped from export. Is that intended?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - you are right , we are not expecting csv files greater than 1MB

Comment: This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: @user1510139, If not "greater than **1**MB",  why compare to 64Mb? We are waiting for your edit

Comment: we are trying to concatenate the *.csv files (size 1MB) contents being written as an parquet file until the parquet file size reaches 64MB

Comment: Goal is to concatenate multiple csv files of small size and write it as parquet file not exceeding 64MB

Comment: @user1510139, the current approach does different than a conception you are describing. It does not look workable in terms the conditions you mentioned and does not look ready to review